# Unable to save gnome sessions in 18.04

Tags: session

I would like to be able to save the session in gnome.
Unfortunately having enabled it in dconf-editor it still doesn't work. Any pointers as to how to save sessions?

Comment: Have you found an answer yet?

Comment: I have not.
I switched back to Debian and am using the hibernate feature of the Linux kernel (4.9) itself, which isn't fraught with its own instability problems. The entire reason why I wanted to do this was to avoid using the hibernate feature of the kernel. Alas not been make much headway either way.